# Create spatial weights matrix that is dependent on time

Tags: r, datetime, matrix, time, spatial

Here is a sample dput:

```
structure(list(county_fips = c(1029L, 6031L, 6105L, 6005L, 1059L, 
6085L, 1067L, 1099L, 1041L, 6055L, 1037L, 6075L, 1021L, 1129L, 
1089L, 1041L, 6105L, 1035L, 6113L, 6113L, 6017L, 1005L, 1103L, 
1101L, 1047L, 1063L, 1035L, 1009L, 1011L, 1009L), year = c(2006L, 
2011L, 2007L, 2014L, 2007L, 2009L, 2009L, 2012L, 2013L, 2013L, 
2003L, 2009L, 2000L, 2015L, 2011L, 2001L, 2011L, 2008L, 2017L, 
2007L, 2010L, 2006L, 2016L, 2016L, 2006L, 2015L, 2006L, 2010L, 
2002L, 2008L), county_longitude = c(-85.5187390554333, -119.815477314422, 
-123.112592108855, -120.651091566386, -87.8437687926026, -121.696289386899, 
-85.2413967560398, -87.3654231637923, -86.3135566195244, -122.330531742296, 
-86.2476641013554, -123.006326413597, -86.7188682695371, -88.20785704033, 
-86.5502148374984, -86.3135602371195, -123.11262599048, -86.9935998663766, 
-121.901570734112, -121.901642250324, -120.524659361727, -85.3932780820398, 
-86.8529424944187, -86.2076187681256, -87.1065036990141, -87.9522257534836, 
-86.9935998663766, -86.5673817538303, -85.7160553695761, -86.5673619519624
), county_latitude = c(33.6745548971238, 36.0754068553086, 40.6506426612768, 
38.4463912923964, 34.441677843473, 37.2325018690902, 31.514723642753, 
31.5708454004793, 31.7315108918912, 38.5064891364823, 32.9362354377436, 
37.6982300529711, 32.8478404198185, 31.4076288265961, 34.7631013026566, 
31.7314913204274, 40.6507062019128, 31.429270562955, 38.6866085969127, 
38.6866751599477, 38.7787311193537, 31.8695648809314, 34.4534685016546, 
32.2202631429857, 32.3258540100126, 32.8531270976181, 31.429270562955, 
33.9808699188007, 32.1004591722918, 33.980889074553), stateid = c(1, 
5, 5, 5, 1, 5, 1, 1, 1, 5, 1, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 1, 5, 5, 5, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)), row.names = c(NA, -30L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x7fdfcf0464e0>)
```

I want to create an inverse-distance spatial weights matrix with the following stipulations:

1.) Observations in different `year` values receive 0 weight.

2.) Observations in different `stateid` values receive 0 weight.

Essentially, this is a time-dependent spatial weights matrix that only assigns positive weight values to counties within the same state and within the same year. However, there seems to be near-zero documentation on dynamic spatial weights matrices online---especially those that restrict positive weights to within-region spatial units. Does anyone have a good set of code or ideas to create a proper dynamic spatial weights matrix? Thank you!